RTK Query: Assign default parameter to every endpoint in baseQuery
We have to work with an API that prefixes all endpoints with a specific value, for example:
GET /foo/<fooId>/post
GET /foo/<fooId>/post/<id>
GET /foo/<fooId>/authors
GET /foo/<fooId>/authors/<id>

The client code is generated using rtk-query-codegen-openapi and it results in interfaces like:
type GetFooByFooIdPostApiArg = {
  fooId: string;
}

type GetFooByFooIdPostByPostIdApiArg = {
  fooId: string;
  id: string;
}

Since the fooId value common for all API calls, I would like to avoid setting it everywhere we use the hooks:
// current
const {data} = useGetFooByFooIdPostByPostId({fooId: "..", id: "..."})

// desired
const {data} = useGetFooByFooIdPostByPostId({id: "..."})

Is there a way to specify a method to retrieve "fooId" in the baseQuery so that the fooId parameter is automatically injected? (assume it's available in a cookie/local-storage/redux state)

You can customize the base query used when the API client is created to include "/foo/:fooId" as part of the base URL used for all endpoints.
Basic Example:
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { selectFooId } from '../path/to/selectFooId';

const customBaseQuery = ({
  baseUrl,
  ...baseQueryArgs
}) => (fetchArgs, api, extraOptions) => {
  const fooId = selectFooId(api.getState());
  // or read from localStorage/etc

  if (!fooId) {
    return {
      error: {
        data: "no foo id"
      }
    };
  }

  return fetchBaseQuery({
    ...baseQueryArgs,
    baseUrl: `${baseUrl}/${fooId}`,
  })(fetchArgs, api, extraOptions);
}

export const Api = createApi({
  baseQuery: customBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "www.my-cool-site.com/foo" }),
  endpoints: builder => ({ .... }),
});

See Constructing a Dynamic Base URL using Redux State for a great overall example.
